# Submit form with token

Tags: web-application, php, attack-prevention, csrf, ajax

I have a token that I want to use to prevent direct access of some php-files.

Some of these php-files are loaded via AJAX.

The token is used with a session to secure form submission AND to prevent direct access of the php-files.

Here's a diagram that I made to explain it a little bit better:

[image: token]

What is more secure? Version 1 or 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number 2 Is more secure because it is simple, and the most common method of implementing a CSRF synchronization token.  Complexity is the enemy of security.   To be honest **I cannot identify a single attack being prevented by measure in #1**,  it seems very superstitious, "cargo cult security".  This security measure doesn't prevent an interception proxy like BURP from accessing the PHP file, and further more no security system should rely upon this measure.  XSS is still a  major problem that could undermine this application (and CSRF sync tokens in general).

I recommend reading the [browser security handbook](https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Main),  and [A Tangled Web](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593273886) to help understated the Same-Origin Policy and ways that it is abused by attackers.